# IAR Compiler warning: "macro does not create a valid token"

Tags: c, compiler-errors, macros, c-preprocessor, compiler-warnings

**I have written the following macro in C:**

```
#define __HAL_CLK_ENABLE(CONTROL_STRUCT,REG,CLK) do { \
SET_BIT(CONTROL_STRUCT->REG,##CONTROL_STRUCT##_##REG##_##CLK##EN);\
} while(0)
```

**Macro call in main.c / All Parameters are defined in cpu specific header files:**

```
__HAL_CLK_ENABLE(RCC,AHB1ENR,GPIOA);
```

**The result should be:**

```
SET_BIT(RCC->AHB1ENR,RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN)
```

This macro works and enables my GPIOA port correctly but I get two Compiler warnings. (IAR EW 7.6)

1. macro Parameter "CONTROL_STRUCT" is used in both expanded and raw forms.
   (I will ignore this warning, because in this case it's right to use both forms!)

***2. concatenation with "RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN" in macro "__HAL_CLK_ENABLE" does not create a valid token.
(What does it mean? Because the token works correctly and my clock is enabled after calling this macro)***

Thanks

**EDIT1:**

Macro definitions:

```
#define SET_BIT(REG, BIT)     ((REG) |= (BIT))

#define RCC                 ((RCC_TypeDef *) RCC_BASE)

typedef struct
{
...                        
__IO uint32_t AHB1ENR;
...
} RCC_TypeDef;

#define GPIOA               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOA_BASE)
```

Comment: You will have to show the definitions of all macros. Please create a minimal example.

Comment: okay, I added all uses macro definitions

Comment: Is it possiblem, that the error depends on the definition of GPIOA?

Comment: Why is there leading `##` on `##CONTROL_STRUCT##_##REG##_##CLK##EN`? It should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The order of evaluation of # and ## operators is unspecified.”  (ISO C99/C11 6.10.3.2, 6.10.3.3) meaning a macro may fail programmer intent with one compiler but not another.

In your case this is not a big deal, as Ouss4 mentions, MISRA-C recommends against multiple # or ## operators, mostly to avoid obfuscation (thus its only an advisory guideline).

However its possible multiple ## operators *could* result in undefined behavior if a ## operation results in an invalid token and this is what IAR is warning about. This and a simple example is discussed at the MISRA-C forum ["Rule 19.12 (# and ## operator) real issue?”](http://www.misra.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=478) :

> `define m(a,b) a##.##b`
>
> `m(1,e30)`
>
> which is defined behavior on a left-to-right evaluation but undefined
>   behavior on right-to-left because .e30 is two preprocessing tokens.

Answer (score 0):

In `##CONTROL_STRUCT##_##REG##_##CLK##EN` remove the first `##`.

Note that what you are doing is error prone and not recommended by embedded coding standards.

MISRA C:

> Rule 19.12 (required): There shall be at most one occurrence of the # or ## operators in
>   a single macro definition.
>
> ---
>
> Rule 19.13 (advisory): The # and ## operators should not be used.